# Azure front door to support multiple web app by path under same domain

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-application-gateway, azure-front-door

I have a question about azure front door potential for this. So I have 2 web site running by Azure App Services and I need then under same domain name but different path of URL like this:

```
App Service A  ->  www.something.com 
App Service B  ->  www.something.com/b-product
```

I'm not sure this is possible to use Azure front door or I should use another service to solve this problem.

Do somebody can suggestion to me?

Comment: Looks like the rules engine should support what you want: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/frontdoor/front-door-tutorial-rules-engine

Answer (score 1):

As suggested by [Junnas](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1658906/juunas) , you can use the front door rules engine

Alternatively , you can use [application gateway listeners](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-gateway/configuration-listeners#listener-type)

- If you want all of your requests (for any domain) to be accepted and forwarded to backend pools, choose basic. Learn how to create an application gateway with a basic listener.
- If you want to forward requests to different backend pools based on the host header or host names, choose multi-site listener, where you must also specify a host name that matches with the incoming request. This is because Application Gateway relies on HTTP 1.1 host headers to host more than one website on the same public IP address and port. To learn more, see hosting multiple sites using Application Gateway.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do this fairly easily, when you create your routing rule you have the option tom specify patterns to match, there you can specify /foo and have this forwarded to pool A where app service A lives

Then you create a different routing rule with /bar pattern to match and forward that to pool B

Then you can repeat this until you get what you need.

you can also have one routing rule match the / domain as per your example you don't have to use a /foo pattern you can also do /* but I always found it easier to use /foo/* and /bar/* to keep the same URL structure